# Error while fetchingh data from my mongo DB cloud database and display it through react native

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, react-native

I connected mongoDB atlas to node js backend server and trying to make the data be displayed on Frontend which is in React Native. I found some sources using the map function to display the data. When i tried it is producing map function not declared error.

```
const TaskDetail = ({ route }) => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      console.log(tasks);
      const response = client
        .get("/api/TasksRoute")
        .then((response) => setTasks(response.data))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err, response.data));

      if (response.data.message === "Fetched tasks successfully") {
      }
      console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error fetching task details:", error);
    }
    // Call the async function immediately
  }, []);

  const { item } = route.params;
  // const [taskDetails, setTaskDetails] = useState([]);
  const [taskVisibility, setTaskVisibility] = useState({
    task1: true,
    task2: true,
    task3: true,
  });

  const toggleTaskVisibility = (taskKey) => {
    setTaskVisibility((prevVisibility) => ({
      ...prevVisibility,
      [taskKey]: !prevVisibility[taskKey],
    }));
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.item}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
        <Text> </Text>

        {/* Display task 1 details */}
        {tasks &&
          tasks.map((task) => {
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.box} key={task._id}>
                <View style={styles.taskDetails}>
                  <Text style={styles.taskTitle}>{task.taskName}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.taskInfo}>Priority: {task.priority}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.taskInfo}>Deadline: {task.deadline}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.taskInfo}>Start: {task.startTime}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.taskInfo}>End: {task.endTime}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.taskInfo}>
                    Duration: {task.temp_duration1}
                  </Text>{" "}
                  {/* You might want to use task.temp_duration1 here */}
                  <Text style={styles.taskInfo}>Date: {task.startDate}</Text>
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.noteDelete}
                  onPress={() =>
                    Alert.alert(
                      "Delete Task",
                      "Are you sure you want to delete?",
                      [
                        {
                          text: "Cancel",
                          onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
                          style: "cancel",
                        },
                        {
                          text: "OK",
                          onPress: () => {
                            toggleTaskVisibility("task1");
                          },
                        },
                      ]
                    )
                  }
                >
                  <Icon name="trash" style={styles.trashIcon}></Icon>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            );
          })}

      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};



export default TaskDetail;
```

this code produces error

> [TypeError: tasks.map is not a function (it is undefined)] undefined

how to solve this

I tried to console.log the data from mongoDB, the data is getting fetched fine.

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(typeof tasks)` just before `tasks.map`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs it says 'object'

Comment: Why isn't it an array?  That's what you are expecting, yes?

Comment: yes. how can I change it to an array? it is appearing fine in the database

Comment: What sets the value of `tasks`?  Perhaps there's an unexpected transformation that you need to track down.